# Android Enable deferred deep linking in GA4F SDK, but Deferred Deep Link response empty

Tags: android

I enable defered deep linking in GA4F SDK, when I do this flow as this link 
[Enable deferred deep linking in your measurement SDK](https://support.google.com/google-ads/answer/12373942?hl=en&ref_topic=10023393&sjid=7022797537979098302-AP#zippy=%2Csteps-to-activate-ddl-in-the-gaf-sdk)
send curl result is status code is 200 
finnal I test  
enable adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE see log show 
FA: Deferred Deep Link feature enabled 
FA: Connected to remote service 
FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 8 
FA: Deferred Deep Link response empty. 
I can't get deeplink info normal? why ? can any one help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check its working or not, with curl commands described in page at your link. Right now, 5 aug 2023 its doesnt work! Something broken at google ad services. You can try to find way to ping google dev team to check issue.

Comment: is that test mode issue, some time in real compaign ad work fine. some way to contact google dev team? is there contact way to get support of my issue

Comment: seems like there is a tech issue, i think need to wait a little.

Comment: at 13 sept, its works and fixed by google dev team

Comment: yes，its works again in test mode

Comment: Doesn't work for me. When I complete those steps and launch my app for the first time, I get this in log: `W/FA: Deferred Deep Link validation failed. gclid, deep link: CLyuzqTeyoEDFYNsfgodpG8Dfg, my_test_deeplink` It manages to use my `AdID` and seems to get the deeplink data, but, since some sort of validation fails, it does not expose it to `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @Starwave Were you able to solve this? I am also facing the same error. `Deferred Deep Link validation failed`

Comment: Haven't tried testing it now, but long story short - I got that deferred deep link from Shared Preferences after I launched the feature in production.

Comment: I tried, it worked, But only receiving utm_source, my url is "https://www.zingoy.com/gift-cards/fastrack?utm_source=TEST_SOURCE&utm_medium=TEST_MEDIUM&utm_campaign=TEST_NAME"

Answer (score 0):

The same issue I tried setting deep link with adid and on validation it giving response code 200 but deep link response is empty.